# Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 Redistributable for Server 2008 R2

Tags: report, viewer

Microsoft Report Viewer 2008 Redistributable for Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.The report data can't display. I searched many sites and can't find the answer, So please help me, Thanks very 
much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use IIS7,You should update your Web IIS Poor,Change to Classic .Net AppPool.And then Refresh your web page, the report data will display. Ths...